# Post a comment against a url

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

If you add a facebook plugin in your site and comment on it, that comments are stored against a url(i.e. your site url) and you can retrieve all those comments by using graph api like below : https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=< URL >.

Here is my question : how to post a comment using graph api for the same url ?

Thanks,Ranjith

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I post new comment with Graph API into Social Comments Box?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7827480/how-can-i-post-new-comment-with-graph-api-into-social-comments-box)